# Make emacs to use only tabs for JS indentation

Tags: indentation, javascript

I've set my tabs to 4 and haven't changed any JS indent settings. All the indents I found in the "JavaScript group" have values either 0 or 4, yet the following code

```
describe('test Info', () => {
    it("should respond with Info", done =>
       doGet("Info", r => {
           expect(r.statusCode).toBe(200);
```

gets indented to columns 4, 7 and 11, while I'd strongly prefer 4, 8 and 12. I guess, Emacs indents `doGet` just below "should...", but I can't see any reason for it. Strangely, it doesn't do this on the next line...

How can I change it?

#### Details

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)

Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Blink-Cursor File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Font-Lock Line-Number
Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Show-Paren Tooltip Transient-Mark

Javascript mode defined in `js.el':

Comment: Line 4 is not strange, because line 3 is not a deeper level of indentation. Instead it is merely aligning function arguments at the same level.

Comment: Which js mode are you using?

Comment: @dcorking OK, it's aligning the `doGet` line, but not the line above it nor the line below it. I guess, the difference is the missing opening brace. Anyway, it's not what I want as I never align arguments (maybe it's common in JS, but I mainly use Java). It's actually deeper as it's inside of the `it(` opening parenthesis. +++ I've added some details to the question.

Comment: Do you want Emacs to indent with tab characters or spaces?

Comment: @dcorking Tabs only. Every indentation should be a single tab. Currently, tabs get used where possible.

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a pure Emacs fix for you. For a lot of my projects, I allow Emacs to call an external formatter, [prettier](https://prettier.io/), that with one setting, does what you want. (Prettier is a free npm package you can install with npm or yarn.)

I installed the prettier-js package from ELPA and initialized it with:

```el
(require-package 'prettier-js)
(require 'prettier-js)
(dolist (hook '(js2-mode-hook js-mode-hook json-mode-hook))
  (add-hook hook 'prettier-js-mode))
```

Then I customized prettier to use tabs by setting `prettier-js-args` to `'("--use-tabs")`. prettier-js formats on save, so on saving your code, I got:

```js
describe("test Info", () => {
    it("should respond with Info", done =>
        doGet("Info", r => {
            expect(r.statusCode).toBe(200);
        }));
});
```

Prettier is quite opinionated, so while it agrees with your opinions here, it may force other formatting changes on your code that you don't like.

Comment: As you wrote, it's quite opinionated. And so am I, unfortunately. `+++` The formatted code from your snippet looks fine according to what I wrote in the question. In the meantime, I've got one more requirement: The closing `}))` on the last but one line close the `it`, so it should be just below it. IOW it closes two things, so it should decrease the indentation by two. `+++` I'm afraid, this is not something, Emacs could be configured to.